# Mysql get min, avg and latest from two tables(products and products-prices)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two Mysql tables:

- `products` with id, name, link
- `products-prices` with id, id_prod, price, availability and date

In the second one, as you can see I can have more prices for the same product depending on the time it was updated, what I want to do is to have one query to show me the lowest price, average price and latest price. I can get first two (lowest and average price) in one query and latest price in another query but I don't know how to concatenate them or if there is another way.

My first query looks like that:

```
SELECT 
    `products`.id AS ids, `products`.name, `products`.link, 
    `products-prices`.id AS id_p, `products-prices`.price, 
    `products-prices`.availability, `products-prices`.date, 
    AVG(`products-prices`.price) AS medie, 
    MIN(`products-prices`.price) AS minim 
FROM
    `products-prices` 
INNER JOIN 
    `products` ON `products`.id = `products-prices`.id_produs 
GROUP BY 
    ids 
ORDER BY 
    ids
```

and the second one is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products-prices`
WHERE date IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(date) max_date 
               FROM `products-prices` 
               GROUP BY id_produs)
```

Can you give me an idea how to combine them? Thank you very much!

(I don't know how UNION works and if it works, I will try it)

//EDIT: And I also have another question, can I get the MIN, AVG values without the latest entry in database ?

Comment: Don't use '-' in table/column identifiers. It's sure to wreak havoc

Comment: I'm generating automatically the database from a website based on category name like for www.something.com/video-cards/ -> video-cards and video-cards-prices (so even if I cut the - from prices I still have it in category name). I will try do to something, thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an untested solution, please let me know if it helps

```
SELECT 
    `products`.id AS ids, `products`.name, `products`.link, 
    `products-prices`.id AS id_p, `products-prices`.price, 
    `products-prices`.availability, `products-prices`.date, 
    AVG(`products-prices`.price) AS medie, 
    MIN(`products-prices`.price) AS minim,
    latest.`date` as latest_date,
    latest.price as latest_price 
FROM
    `products-prices` 
INNER JOIN 
    `products` ON `products`.id = `products-prices`.id_produs 
INNER JOIN
    (select id_produs, price, `date` 
     from `products-prices` t1
     where not exists (select 1
                       from `products-prices` t2
                       where t1.`date` < t2.`date` and t1.id_produs = t2.id_produs)
     group by id_produs
    ) latest     
ON
    latest.id_produs = products.id
GROUP BY 
    ids 
ORDER BY 
    ids
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subselect for the max date

```
  select 
      `products`.id AS ids, 
      `products`.name, 
      `products`.link,
      t.date,
      t.price,
      t.availability,
       AVG(`products-prices`.price) AS medie, 
       MIN(`products-prices`.price) AS minim 

  from  `products`
  inner join `products-prices`  ON `products`.id=`products-prices`.id_produs 
  inner join ( )
  select id_produs, date, price, availability
  from `products-prices` 
  where ( id_produs, date ) = (
  select id_produs, max(date) as max_date
  from `products-prices` 
  group by id ) t on t.id_produs = `products`.id_prod
```